# Laravel/Eloquent mutate model on join

Tags: php, laravel, join, eloquent, mutators

I'm trying to mutate a model to display an array of strings and not an array of objects.

Current Output

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "company_name": "blah"
  "language": [
    {
      "name": "English"
    },
    {
      "name": "French"
    }
  ] 
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "company_name": "blah2"
  "language": [
    {
      "name": "English"
    },
    {
      "name": "French"
    }
  ] 
}
```

Desired Output

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "company_name": "blah"
  "language": ["English","French"]
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "company_name": "blah2"
  "language": ["English","French"]
}
```

Partner Model

```
class Partner extends Eloquent
{

   protected $table = 'property_managers';
   protected $visible = array('id','company_name','language');

    public function language(){
       return $this->belongsToMany('Language', 'property_manager_language', 'property_manager_id', 'language_id');
    }

}
```

Language Model

```
class Language extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'languages';
    protected $visible = array('name');

    public function propertyManager()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany('PropertyManager');
    }
}
```

I'm accessing it via the code snippet below

`$pm = Partner::with('language')->get();`

I looked into mutators but it doesn't seem to hit that attribute within the partner model.

```
public function getLanguageAttribute(){
   //run my code to flatten to array
}
```

So I'm curious as to if mutators don't work on joins or how you would be able to modify the return on the join. I can add a mutator to the Language model but that will only modify the attributes of that specific model. Any insight would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your model,

```
public function getLanguagesAttribute(){
   return array_pluck(collect($this->language)->toArray(), 'name');
}
```

luego prueba con esto

```
$partner = Partner::find(1);
return $partner->languages;
```